# Where did these iOS settings come from?

Tags: xamarin.ios, bundle, settings

I am making a Xamarin app and trying to figure out how to handle notification settings. I noticed that the iOS version somehow has these settings already there even though there is no setting bundle in the files.[image] Since there’s no settings bundle, where did these come from and can I access them instead of creating a bundle with duplicate settings? Thank you I’m advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that the iOS version somehow has these settings already
> there even though there is no setting bundle in the files.

The iOS notification setting in your screenshot is create by default by system. The notification permission is closed here by default. It is controlled at system level. You can't change this setting programmatically.

> can I access them instead of creating a bundle with duplicate
> settings

No it's system setting and you can't access it. User can go to setting and choose to close/open notification of specific app here.

What you need to do about [notification in your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos) is your configurations of your app notification. You can request the notification permission when your app run, then user will choose `allow/not allow` notification. If use choose `allow/not allow` in the app, the result will list in the notifications page in the iOS setting(`Notifications` in your screenshot).